# dynamic contents of viewPager are not shown first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `viewPager` which uses `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as adapter and in fragment class which is used in `getItem()` function of adapter I add some other fragments at runtime using fragment manager. Fragments are shown correctly for page zero (starting page) but for any other page I should swipe over it an then swipe back to it to see contents.(as I checked each swipe causes inner fragments and fragment managers behave correctly even the first time but nothing is shown at first)
Any solution is appreciated
Thanks in advance

**adapter code in main class**

```
class FragmntProducer extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public FragmntProducer(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new PagerFragment(pager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

}
```

**fragment class used for viewpager**

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {

WeekView rowOne , rowTwo , rowThree , rowFour , rowFive , rowSix;
int cis;

public PagerFragment(int ci) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    cis = ci;
//      Toast.makeText(getContext(), ci+"under construct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_fragment_layout, container, false);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"page: "+cis,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//      rowOne = new WeekView();
//      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.week_one, rowOne).commit();
    rowTwo = new WeekView();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.week_two, rowTwo).commit();
//      rowThree = new WeekView();
//      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.week_three, rowThree).commit();
    rowFour = new WeekView();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.week_four, rowFour).commit();
    rowFive = new WeekView();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.week_five, rowFive).commit();
    rowSix = new WeekView();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.week_six, rowSix).commit();
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return layout;
}
```

}

**xml layout for fragment of viewPager**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/week_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:name="com.cal.calendar.WeekView"/>

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/week_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/week_three"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:name="com.cal.calendar.WeekView"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/week_four"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/week_five"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:name="com.cal.calendar.WeekView"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/week_six"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

Comment: Could you please include the relevant code in the body of your post?

Comment: @Tom Lord code is added hope it helps you figure out what's wrong with it